# Why does this code contain case 0 and default?

Tags: c, linux

I don't understand why the switch statement contains `case 0:` and `default:`?

```
int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = create_process();
    switch (pid)
    {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
            break;
        case 0:
            child_process();
            break;
        default:
            father_process(pid);
            break;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `break` after the return statement

Comment: I can't find `create_process` in linux man pages, but I assume the `pid` can be any value and identifies the systems pid for the process in the system, hence the `default` is executed.

Comment: Please see [ask]. How precisely do you know that it executes both cases?

Comment: sorry but i was not able to put my entire code in the box...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are creating a new process, the code executes the switch statement twice (in two different processes).

Assuming you are using `fork()` inside `create_process()`, in the parent process, the `pid` variable contains the child PID (strictly positive). Thus, the switch entry point is default.
In the child process, `pid` is 0, thus the entry point is case 0.